# How to use OpenCV VideoWriter properly?

Tags: python, opencv, video-capture

I would like to crop a region of a video, and save it.
I used the following code to do it.

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('input.avi')
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 25, (1280, 720))

while True:
    ret, image_np = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        break;

    roi = image_np[300:1020, 0:1280]
    out.write(roi)

cap.release()
out.release()
```

Video file is created, and I can watch in a media player, but if a want to read this file in python, I get an error message.

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('output.avi')
_, image_np = cap.read()
```

**Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)**

I think the problem is with the video I made, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 2):

`cv2.VideoWriter` expects the size of the frame to be same as the frame you write. `roi` shape is not `(1280, 720)`.

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('input.avi')
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 25, (1280, 720))
writerInit = False
while True:
    ret, image_np = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        break;

    roi = image_np[300:1020, 0:1280]
    if(not writerInit):
        h,w,_ = roi.shape
        out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 25, (w, h))
        writerInit = True

    out.write(roi)

cap.release()
out.release()
```

Comment: I tried your code, but unforunately, It didn't help. (And I printed (w, h), the result is 1280, 720.

Comment: If you are slicing your `image_np`. The size can't be `1280,720`. Can you try creating your video with `cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')`?

Comment: It does not help :(